# (duplicate) [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm asking this type of question although people already asked for its answers but I couldn't fix my problem still.

I've made a python code (from a learning course about networking) that goes like this :

```
import socket

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',8820))
my_socket.send('omer'.encode())
data = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print('The server sent:' + data)
my_socket.close()
```

the error I'm getting is this `Traceback (most recent call last): File "e:/VISUAL STUDIO CODE/the good stuff/networking learning/ex2_1.py", line 4, in <module> my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',8820)) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

any explanation for why it doesn't run this simple code would be great, thanks

*edit: I used both visual studio code and pycharm to run this and got the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of this error is simple: it means that there is no server process on IP address 127.0.0.1 (your own computer) which is listening to port 8820.

If you want to connect to a port you must choose an IP address and port where there is a server running.

You were probably supposed to run a server program on your computer and then run this client program at the same time.

Comment: Ok I think I get it but how do I run a server program that allows me to connect to this IP address and port 8820? It's not specified in the PDF that I'm using to learn this stuff

Comment: ok I searched and did it, thank you man for explaining